# facebook fql returning album id's with an underscore

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

i have this fql statement

```
$fql_query  =   array(
 'method' => 'fql.query',
 'query' => 'SELECT aid, owner, name from album WHERE owner = ' . $uid
);
$albums = $facebook->api($fql_query);
```

the print_r dump of the return contains aid= matching the id of the owner rather than the id of the actual album. but the aid is return not only with the user id but with extra info tagged on to the end like "*43367" for one album and another album has "*-3" tagged on to it

2 questions then

1. why is the owner id being returned instead of the correct album id
2. and whats being tagged on to the end of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [album](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album) table docs it says that returned `aid` is unique for every user and is a string. So the value you receive is "correct" in a sense that you can use it for this particular user wherever you need album id.

Maybe you are interested in `object_id` field instead?

Comment: what i am doing is selecting all the albums of the user then selecting all the photos associated with that album..

Comment: @Chris So did you run into problems? Just use returned `aid` for retrieving photos from a `photo` table

Comment: i used AID and it still not working, its still returning aid as 100000466817657_-3 which will not relate to the other photo table id. I don't understand how "The aid is unique only for a given user." Using object_id returns empty arrays.

Comment: i ended up using the graph api to combat this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap the aid in quotes when running this query, because it is a string. So it would look like this:

query=SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid = '[OWNERID_ALBUMID]'&access_token=[token]

Answer (score 0):

In FQL, the object_id in album is the same as the id you get when using the graph API. So, use object_id instead of aid.